# How to get a list of modified fields with ScriptRunner on IssueUpdated event?

Tags: groovy, jira

In my Jira instance, I created a Script Listener for the IssueUpdated event using the ScriptRunner add-on and I'm trying to get a list of the changed fields. For some reason the method getModifiedFields() is coming empty, somebody can help me to fix that?

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultIssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue

log.setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG)

Issue mainIssue = event.issue

MutableIssue mutableIssue = (MutableIssue)mainIssue
def modFields = mutableIssue.getModifiedFields()
log.debug("Modified fields count: "+modFields.count) // null
log.debug("Modified fields: "+modFields.toString()) //  [:]
log.debug("Original Ticket: "+mainIssue.key) // EPS-39
```

Answer (score 2):

After turning google upside down I've found the answer to my question. More background here: my final goal is to update a target Jira ticket (in another project) with whatever was changed in the main ticket. I have a custom field that contains the original ticket key, so I can track it down (ex: ticket "PRJ-1" -> "Original Ticket": "TRG-1"). To do this I'm going to ScriptRunner -> Script listeners -> custom listener and adding an "Issue Updated" listener.

I'm still stuck in the part where I have a custom label field as you can see by the comments in the end of the code, but at least I could manage to get a list of the changed fields in my main ticket.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultIssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParameters
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.DefaultIssueService

log.setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG)

def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
Issue mainIssue = event.issue
// Get Custom Field Object "Original Ticket"
def originalTicket = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Original Ticket")
// Get Value of the Custom Field Object "Original Ticket"
String targetTicketKey = mainIssue.getCustomFieldValue(originalTicket).toString()

// Get Original Ticket Object based on the custom field value
def targetIssue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(targetTicketKey)

// Get list of modified values in the original ticket to update target ticket
List<GenericValue> changeItemsList = event.getChangeLog().getRelated("ChildChangeItem")
Iterator<GenericValue> changeItemListIterator = changeItemsList.iterator()
Object oldValue
Object newValue
def userManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager()
def auser = userManager.getUserByKey("Sync User")
def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
CustomField custom
// Loop for all the changed fields
while (changeItemListIterator.hasNext()) {
    GenericValue changeItem = (GenericValue)changeItemListIterator.next()
    String currentFieldName = changeItem.get("field").toString()
    log.debug("Current field: "+currentFieldName)
    oldValue = changeItem.get("oldstring")
    newValue = changeItem.get("newstring")
    if (oldValue != null && newValue != null){
        log.debug("Field changed from: "+oldValue+" to "+newValue)
        switch (currentFieldName){
            case "summary": 
              log.debug("Found switch: Summary")
              targetIssue.setSummary(newValue.toString())
            break
            case "description": 
              log.debug("Found switch: Description")
              targetIssue.setDescription(newValue.toString())
            break
            case "Affected Version(s)": 
              log.debug("Found switch: Affected Version(s)")
              // This is a label field. I'm stuck here and I don't know how to manipulate the value.
              // Labels are a set type, studing more about it.
              custom = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Affected Version(s)")
              targetIssue.setCustomFieldValue(custom,newValue)
            break
            default: log.debug("Not found: "+currentFieldName)
        }
    }
    // Update my target Issue (in another project) that I'm trying to synchronize with the main issue.
    issueManager.updateIssue(auser, targetIssue,  com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption.DO_NOT_DISPATCH, false)    
}
```

Comment: This is giving me the following error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Set

Answer (score 1):

`mutableIssue.modifiedFields` used only in scripted Validators.

Iterating through modified fileds in scripted Listener:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> fieldsModified = event.getChangeLog()?.getRelated('ChildChangeItem') as List<HashMap<String, Object>>

for (HashMap<String, Object> field : fieldsModified) 
    log.debug("Field: ${field["field"]}, old value: ${field["oldstring"]}, new value: ${field["newstring"]}.")
```

Affected versions is a system field like Summary and Description. Use `issue.affectedVersions` to update it.

Comment: Thank you. I could figure this out as well. Right now I'm struggling to update a custom field of type label and another one of type option list. Do you have some code for that?